# Text output tab not appearing in NUnit with ReSharper

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, resharper

I don't have the text output tab, only the output tab, in my NUnit output. This is very disturbing, as I need to display some debug infos. This is a screenshot:

[image]

I am using VS 2013 with ReSharper 8.1.

Comment: Do you mean the "test output tab", or the "text output tab"?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a separate text output tab. The output tab will display the results of the test - any test being output and also any exception messages and stack traces.